# Buscar en documento referenciado usando Mongoose

Tags: javascript, mongoose

Quiero hacer una búsqueda en la misma consulta en `Mongoose`.

Tengo un modelo de `Activity` y otro de `Category`, donde `activity` hace referencia a `category`.

Mi consulta a `Activity`:

```
{
      _id: 5e0ac92f4ee5f53270ff6744,
      category: 'H',
      anual_amount: 1151066.58,
      max_electricity: 20000,
      area: 200,
      max_rent_amount: 207191.98,
      sipa_amount: 961.32,
      tax_integrated: 4604.26,
      obra_social_amount: 689,
      __v: 0,
      id: '5e0ac92f4ee5f53270ff6744'
    }
  ],
  _id: 5e0ac9f84ee5f53270ff6745,
  description: 'Locaciones y/o prestamos de servicios',
  __v: 0,
  id: '5e0ac9f84ee5f53270ff6745'
}
```

Lo que he probado:

```
  console.log(await Activity.find({ "category.area": 30 }));
```

Pero me devuelve vacío.

Problema:

Deseo hacer un filtrado de `category` desde `activity`.

He probado algunas opciones pero aún no he tenido éxito.

Comment: El ejemplo de lo que devuelve tu consulta a `Activity` está mal o incompleto. Tienes un corchete de cierre (`]`), pero ninguno que abra. Además, faltaría el nombre del campo o propiedad a la que pertenece esa parte del código. Si puedes agregar más detalles podría ayudarte. Saludos